# Webpacker not working for jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Okay, so this is really odd behavior. Here are the steps to reproduce my problem:

1. run `yarn add jquery-filepond`
2. add `import 'jquery-filepond'` in application.js

That's it! And the error I get in my console is this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery-filepond'
```

Seems like a really silly error right? I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to fix your problem (I'm using `npm` here, feel free to adapt that to `yarn` if you prefer that):

1. You need to install jQuery and FilePond dependencies yourself.

   ```
   npm i jquery filepond --save
   ```
2. Because `jquery-filepond` requires `$`, `jQuery` and `FilePond` to be variables in the global namespace (which alone is a no-go):

   ```
   import { $, jQuery } from 'jquery';
   window.$ = $;
   window.jQuery = jQuery;
   import * as FilePond from 'filepond';
   window.FilePond = FilePond;
   ```
3. Last, because the jquery-filepond package.json's "main" entry points to a non-existent `index.js`, you need to explicitly import a specific file from that package:

   ```
   import 'jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery';
   ```

I really recommend to step away from that plugin as it seems to be very poorly programmed (as so many - especially older - jQuery plugins).

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ugyp8q

Comment: Why bundle jquery? Webpack providePlugin maybe?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Feel free to give a better answer.

Comment: Yes, i'm looking at other ones now, but everything I find seems to be a jquery plugin lol.